# Given a crystal with mirror symmetry along a lattice plane, how to find the correspond plane in first Brillouin zone

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals, tight-binding

Given a crystal with mirror symmetry along a lattice plane, how to find the correspond invariant plane in first Brillouin zone?